# Error related to rxjs uprade to 6 "switchMap is not a function"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, rxjs6

```
 return auth.refreshToken().switchMap((token) => {
                if (token) {

                    return next.handle(this.addToken(req));
                }

                // If we don't get a new token, logout.
                auth.logoutUser(0);
                return empty;

            }).catch((e: any) => {
                // If there is an exception calling 'refreshToken', logout.
                auth.logoutUser(0);
                return empty;
            }).finally(() => {
                this.isRefreshingToken = true;
            });
```

This was working perfectly fine with Angular.

**"rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.3",**

Once upgraded,

**"@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
 "rxjs": "^6.0.0"**

I'm getting run time error

```
"ApiService::handleError TypeError: auth.refreshToken(...).switchMap is not a function
".
```

On searching found out the solution is to add pipe, So added

```
 return auth.refreshToken().pipe(switchMap((token) => {
                if (token) {

                    return next.handle(this.addToken(req));
                }

                // If we don't get a new token, logout.
                auth.logoutUser(0);
                return empty;

            }).catch((e: any) => {
                // If there is an exception calling 'refreshToken', logout.
                auth.logoutUser(0);
                return empty;
            }).finally(() => {
                this.isRefreshingToken = true;
            });
```

But it throws new compile time error

```
Argument of type '(token: {}) => Observable<HttpEvent<any>> | ((scheduler?: SchedulerLike) => Observable<never>)' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}, index: number) => ObservableInput<HttpEvent<any>>'."
```

It looks like the problem with rxjs upgrade , what will be the fix for this ?

Modified import from,

```
import { switchMap } from "rxjs/operators"; to 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

Now it gives error to below section of code **" error TS2304: Cannot find name 'switchMap'."**

```
 return this.tokenSubject.pipe(
                filter(token => token != null),
                take(1),
                switchMap(token => {
                    return next.handle(this.addToken(req));
                })
            );
```

Comment: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';`

Comment: It gives new error on changing import from import { switchMap } from "rxjs/operators"; to 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';.. updated in question

Comment: Did you try all the steps listed at https://update.angular.io/ when doing your angular upgrade?

Comment: @Capricorn yes tried

Answer (score 2):

The quick fix is to install rxjs-compat and you old code shouldn't require any changes. However, Rxjs 6 is more stable version for the features introduced in the 5th version. So would recommand you go back to the documentation and migrate your imports and rxjs uses to Rxjs 6.

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```